# The use of `this` keyword in click handler when passed in from middle man function

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I originally have a click event handler in jQuery like this

```
jQuery('#btn').click(_eventHandler);
```

Which then handles the event like

```
function _eventHandler(e){
    jQuery(this).text('Clicked');
}
```

then the `this` keyword exacts as an alias to the DOM element of the button that was clicked, correct?

But now, I need to change this logic so there is a flag to check for something else like

```
jQuery('#btn').click(function(e){
    if(blah){
         _eventHandler(e);
    }else{
        _dosomethingElse(e);
    }
});
```

then will the `this` keyword in _eventHandler still work correctly?  I basically need to do a check before the _eventHandler is called, but I do not want to change the actual function for the _eventHandler and place this logic inside there. Will `this` still work?

Comment: why not try it yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pass its reference in the methods:

```
jQuery('#btn').click(function(e){
    if(blah){
         _eventHandler(e,this);
    }else{
        _dosomethingElse(e,this);
    }
});
```

and access them in function:

```
function _dosomethingElse(event,element)
{
   $(element).text("Else called");
}

function  _eventHandler(event,element)
{
  $(element).text("Event Called");
}
```

**Note:** By this way now `_eventHandler` cannot be used as direct event handler for button click,because it is not now a direct event handler as you were doing preciously this way `jQuery('#btn').click(_eventHandler);` but now it is different.

Comment: Ok, I thought of that but it just felt weird to me. I will just do that

Comment: Worth pointing out that `_eventHandler` can't directly be used as event handler anymore.

Answer (score 5):

If you want `this` set in your functions, you can use `.call()` to cause it to be set accordingly:

```
jQuery('#btn').click(function(e){
    if(blah) {
         _eventHandler.call(this, e);
    } else {
        _dosomethingElse.call(this, e);
    }
});
```

This allows you to use the same function either called by yourself or as a direct event handler because `this` and the arguments will be set identically.

Every function has both a `.call()` and `.apply()` method which allow you to set the `this` value when calling a function.   You would use `.call()` when you have a specific number of arguments to pass and you would use `.apply()` if you have an array of arguments (often of unknown length).  See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify to the answer already given, "this" keyword always refers to the object that the function or method is operating off of. So in your function '_eventHandler' this was refering to the '_eventHandler' function. Jquery passes the 'selector' object to each of it methods so you could make event handler and extenstion on jQuery prototype. like this...(by the way Jquery.fn = jQuery.prototype

```
  jQuery.fn._eventHandler= function () {
      jQuery(this).text('Clicked');
  }
```

... and call is like

```
    jQuery('.yourSelector').click(function() {
            jQuery(this)._eventHandler();
    });
```

...and jquery would pass the yourSelecotr as 'this'

Comment: There's no need to create a jQuery method just to set the `this` value - that would be useful only if you were going to use the method from multiple places.  Also, the `this` value in a jQuery method will be the jQuery object itself that it was called on, NOT the DOM element so there's no need for the extra `jQuery(this)` you have in your method (it doesn't stop it from working, but it's redundant).

Comment: Right thanks for the clarification, great answer by the way. I think that your explanation of the .apply() method was more relevant. I thought the OP would benefit from knowing how to create a method on an object (in this case the jQuery object) for future coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try it out:

```
function fn(ev) {
    console.log('fn ' + this);
}

$('button').click(function (ev) {
    function nested(ev) {
        console.log('nested ' + this);
    }

    console.log('click ' + this);
    fn(ev);
    nested(ev);
    fn.call(this, ev);
});
```

Output:

```
"click [object HTMLButtonElement]"
"fn [object Window]"
"nested [object Window]"
"fn [object HTMLButtonElement]"
```

`this` context is set to window when you call a function. You can use the method `Function.prototype.call(thisContext [, arg1 ...])` to set the `this` context explicitly.